# Domain of square root of a fraction with variables in the denominator and numerator

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I've been playing around with function
$$f(x)=\sqrt{\frac{x+2}{x+1}}$$
I tried to find its domain, and I did so with finding the interval in which this applies
$${({x\geq-2}\wedge{x\gt-1})}\vee{({x\leq-2}\wedge{x\lt-1})}$$
which in turn gave this domain
$$D(f)\in{(-\infty;-2>\cup{(-1;\infty)}}$$
(I am using standard Czech notation which differs from anglosaxon, in intervals we use <,> instead of [,])

Now all is well and fine, however, I thought to myself: "I should be able to apply this identity $\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}=\frac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{b}}$ and the domain should not change."

Now when I solved for the domain of $f(x)=\frac{\sqrt{x+2}}{\sqrt{x+1}}$, the domain turned out to be only
$$D(f)\in(-1;\infty)$$
which I know is wrong. Upon further investigation I was able to get the other interval with $f(x)=\frac{\sqrt{-(x+2)}}{\sqrt{-(x+1)}}$ and get
$$D(f)\in{(-\infty;-2>}$$
Now comes the question, had I not known the first way which i referenced of finding the domain and only used the identity with distributed square roots and then not checked the result. How would I have known that that was not the complete solution  and that I should have also used the equation with negative polynomials under the square roots. Is there some rule that I am missing or something?

For graphs of the functions see https://www.desmos.com/calculator/jk14w994q3

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan no it isn't

Comment: @KennyLau I conpletely forgot about  that part of the answer. Thank you for helping to refresh my memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
x \in D(f)
&\iff& \dfrac{x+2}{x+1} \ge 0 \\
&\iff& (x+2)(x+1) \ge 0 \\
&\iff& (x+1.5)^2 \ge 0.5^2 \\
&\iff& x+1.5 \le -0.5 \lor x+1.5 \ge 0.5 \\
&\iff& x \le -2 \lor x \ge -1
\end{array}$$

---

Also $\sqrt{ab} = \sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$ is only valid when $a, b > 0$. Same with $\sqrt{\frac ab} = \frac{\sqrt a}{\sqrt b}$.

Comment: I am not sure how you manipulated the expression, but that does not matter. I once knew that rule but it seems i have forgotten thanks for your help.